# after initialising session in one controller i am n't able use the session id for another controller and nor i am able to use it in different page

Tags: php, session, continuous-integration, codeigniter-3

version 3.19 and i am having problem in session .

sceneraio:

i have loaded session libraray in config folder and  controller.

```
 public function __construct() 
{
          parent::__construct();
             $this->load->library('session'); 
                                 $this->load->model('product_model');

 }
```

problem: after initialising session in one controller i am n't able use the session id for another controller and  nor i am able to use it in different page.

Comment: how do you try to use session in other controllers ?

Comment: i just want to check session is set or not  so that i can redirect the page. and also can get session id.

Comment: if ($this->session->set_userdata('cusid')){
              redirect('main');
          }

Comment: `set_userdata('cusid')` is only for adding or updating session data, but if you want to check data session or retrieve it from session you have to use `userdata('cusid')` or `has_userdata('cusid')`

Answer (score 0):

As you want a session to be created if the user is logged in, or not then why not use the autoloader (./application/config/autoload.php)?

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

Comment: #Thibaut BOULDOIRE  i have already loaded session in autoload.